# Auto-run python script when system is booted on jetson nano

Tags: python-3.x, nvidia-jetson, startupscript, nvidia-jetson-nano

How to auto-run python script made by me when the system is booted on jetson nano?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Create a shell file.

sudo nano /usr/local/bin/startup.sh: Type this on the terminal. A new sh file is created. This file consists of the python file that is to be executed. I gave the name startup.sh. It can be any name XYZ.sh

#! /bin/sh: This is called the shebang. This would execute our script using a Bourne shell. This tells the system that the commands in this file should be fed to the interpreter.

sleep 10: This pauses a script for a certain amount of time. He re we pause it for 10 seconds.

In the next line, we insert the code that we use to run the program on the terminal.
OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8 /usr/bin/python3 path/of/the/python/code.py

It looks like this:

`#! /bin/sh`

`sleep 10`

`OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8 /usr/bin/python3 /home/sooraj/Downloads/incabin-monitoring-system-main/netstreamfeb17.py`
Now we close the file using Ctrl+X. and save it.

Step 2: Create a service file

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/startup.service`

Things to write inside it.

`[Unit]`

`Description = INTU_IPC start-uo specific script`

`[Service]`

`Type= idle`

`ExecStartPre = /bin/sleep 10`

`ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/startup.sh`

`User=sooraj`# write your user name here

`[Install]`

`WantedBy = multi-user.target`

Now we close the file using Ctrl+X. and save it.

step 3: Give permission.

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh`

step 4: enable, start and stop

`sudo systemctl enable startup.service`

`sudo systemctl start startup.service`

`sudo systemctl stop.service`

After starting, to view if it works, we can observe it in the terminal by

`journalctl -u startup.service -f`
If we edit the service file for the next time, we need to reload it before enabling and starting.

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl enable startup.service`

`sudo systemctl start startup.service`
Additional information.

`systemctl is-enabled startup.service` #checks if the service file is enabled.

`systemctl is-failed startup.service` #checks if the service file failed to start.

`systemctl is-active startup.service` #checks if the service file is active.

`sudo systemctl list-unit-files — type=service` #display the list of service files.

Comment: This may seem complex, but it allows things like restart on crash via e.g.

Restart=on-failure

RestartSec=5s

in the service section. It also logs status nicely, and other integrations with the OS work well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `StartupApplications` and add your python execution shell command with proper path.
An even better solution will be to use `crontab`.

```
crontab -e
```

Add `@reboot python path/to/script` so that the script gets executed every time you reboot.
This [link](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/running-scripts-at-boot) might help you.

Comment: I solved it by using a shell script and systemd service but because my code includes cv2 for using the camera I get a new error "can't open display" and I am trying to solve it now  .thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to systemd or crontab, you can try [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/). It's very easy to configure and use. Just follow a quick start guide. Or just test it the following way:

```
pm2 start app.py
pm2 save
```

Note that you should initially generate a [startup script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/) to make it work on boot.